# Force table on the same page as section title

Tags: tables, landscape

how can I make sure the table is on the same page as the section title? I have tried adding [h!] to \begin{table}, which does nothing. Note that the table is in landscape mode.

[image]

Table:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}[t]{lcccccccccccc}
\toprule
  & emp & emp\_incq1 & emp\_incq2 & emp\_incq3 & emp\_incq4 & emp\_incmiddle & emp\_incbelowmed & emp\_incabovemed & emp\_ss40 & emp\_ss60 & emp\_ss65 & emp\_ss70\\
\midrule
Treat x After & \num{-0.007} & \num{0.006} & \num{-0.003} & \num{-0.004} & \num{-0.018}+ & \num{0.002} & \num{-0.003} & \num{-0.006} & \num{0.017} & \num{-0.004} & \num{-0.008} & \num{-0.038}+\\
 & (\num{0.012}) & (\num{0.018}) & (\num{0.015}) & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.013}) & (\num{0.015}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.018}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.020})\\
Konstant & \num{-0.083}*** & \num{-0.190}*** & \num{-0.031}*** & \num{-0.059}*** & \num{-0.008}+ & \num{-0.048}*** & \num{-0.137}*** & \num{-0.017}*** & \num{-0.126}*** & \num{-0.137}*** & \num{-0.108}*** & \num{-0.167}***\\
 & (\num{0.006}) & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.004}) & (\num{0.006}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.013})\\
\midrule
Num.Obs. & \num{570} & \num{528} & \num{498} & \num{525} & \num{420} & \num{513} & \num{570} & \num{510} & \num{540} & \num{480} & \num{510} & \num{540}\\
R2 & \num{0.863} & \num{0.813} & \num{0.882} & \num{0.903} & \num{0.941} & \num{0.904} & \num{0.808} & \num{0.904} & \num{0.726} & \num{0.873} & \num{0.805} & \num{0.797}\\
R2 Adj. & \num{0.849} & \num{0.793} & \num{0.869} & \num{0.893} & \num{0.934} & \num{0.894} & \num{0.789} & \num{0.894} & \num{0.698} & \num{0.859} & \num{0.785} & \num{0.776}\\
R2 Within &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
R2 Pseudo &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
AIC & \num{-2623.7} & \num{-1828.7} & \num{-2054.8} & \num{-2417.0} & \num{-2337.2} & \num{-2306.4} & \num{-2350.7} & \num{-2414.6} & \num{-2013.0} & \num{-2159.1} & \num{-2125.1} & \num{-1679.2}\\
BIC & \num{-2393.4} & \num{-1606.7} & \num{-1844.3} & \num{-2203.8} & \num{-2163.4} & \num{-2090.1} & \num{-2120.4} & \num{-2207.1} & \num{-1794.2} & \num{-1962.9} & \num{-1917.6} & \num{-1460.3}\\
Log.Lik. & \num{1364.856} & \num{966.334} & \num{1077.391} & \num{1258.501} & \num{1211.581} & \num{1204.196} & \num{1228.360} & \num{1256.318} & \num{1057.525} & \num{1126.532} & \num{1111.542} & \num{890.587}\\
Std.Errors & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{13}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}\textsuperscript{1} TODO: Fotnot till denna tabell}\\
\multicolumn{13}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}+ p $<$ 0.1, * p $<$ 0.05, ** p $<$ 0.01, *** p $<$ 0.001}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The table seems so large that it require a page on its own. If you want it on the same page, try using `\tiny` after `\centering` and see what happens.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small but compilable document which reproduce your problem. Showed image is not produced by your code fragment.

Comment: Resize a table is always a bad idea. Just use  smaller font consistently through the document for big tables. If `\footnotesize` is not enough, consider the redesign the contents (split, transpose rows to columns, simplify headers, show the information without a table, etc.).

Comment: Please tell us more about how exactly you switch back and forth between portrait and landscape mode.

Answer (score 2):

To long for the comment. Your table is to wide that can be fit on portrait oriented page, so rotate it is only reasonable option. For this you can use `rotating` package  or `rotatebox` as defined in the `graphicx` package.

However, solution can be simpler if it is allowed that section tile can be rotated too.

Do you expect something like this:

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}
\newcommand\td{\textsuperscript{\textdagger}}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\section{Section name}

\vfill
\begin{center}
\begin{sideways}
    \small\linespread{0.8}\selectfont
\sisetup{
    input-open-uncertainty =,
    input-close-uncertainty=,
    table-align-text-before= false,
    table-format=-1.3{***}
        }   
\begin{talltblr}[
note{a} = {Prefix to column header names}
note{} = {\mbox{}\\
          Standard errors in parentheses:\newline
          \td:  $p<0.1$,\quad
          *:    $p<0.05$,\quad
          **:   $p<0.01$,\quad
          ***:  $p<0.001$.
          }
                 ]{width=0.75\textheight,
                   colsep=3pt,
                   colspec = {@{} X[l, m]
                              *{12}{S} @{}}
                   }
\toprule
    &   \SetCell[c=11]{c}  {{{ emp\_ \TblrNote{a} }}}                             \\
    \cmidrule{3-13}
    &{{{emp}}}     &{{{incq1}}}   &{{{incq2}}}   &{{{incq3}}}   &{{{incq4}}}   &{{{incmiddle}}}
    &{{{incbmed}}} &{{{incamed}}} &{{{ss40}}}    &{{{ss60}}}    &{{{ss65}}}    &{{{ss70}}}    \\
\midrule
Treat x\newline After
    & -0.007    &  0.006    & -0.003    & -0.004    & -0.018\td &  0.002
    & -0.003    & -0.006    &  0.017    & -0.004    & -0.008    & -0.038\td     \\
%
    & (0.012)   & (0.018)   & (0.015)   & (0.010)   & (0.011)   & (0.013)
    & (0.015)   & (0.011)   & (0.018)   & (0.011)   & (0.009)   & (0.020)       \\
\addlinespace
Konstant
    & -0.083\TblrNote{***}
                & -0.190\TblrNote{***}
                            & -0.031\TblrNote{***}
                                        & -0.059\TblrNote{***}
                                                    & -0.008\td & -0.048\TblrNote{***}
    & -0.137\TblrNote{***}
                & -0.017\TblrNote{***}
                            & -0.126\TblrNote{***}
                                        & -0.137\TblrNote{***}  
                                                    & -0.108\TblrNote{***}
                                                                & -0.167***     \\
%
    & (0.006)   & (0.010)   & (0.008)   & (0.005)   & (0.004)   & (0.006)
    & (0.008)   & (0.005)   & (0.009)   & (0.005)   & (0.008)   & (0.013)           \\
    \midrule

Num.Obs. 
    & {{{570}}} & {{{528}}} & {{{498}}} & {{{525}}} & {{{420}}} & {{{513}}} 
    & {{{570}}} & {{{510}}} & {{{540}}} & {{{480}}} & {{{510}}} & {{{540}}}     \\
R2  & 0.863     & 0.813     & 0.882     & 0.903     & 0.941     & 0.904 
    & 0.808     & 0.904     & 0.726     & 0.873     & 0.805     & 0.797         \\
R2 Adj. 
    & 0.849     & 0.793     & 0.869     & 0.893     & 0.934     & 0.894 
    & 0.789     & 0.894     & 0.698     & 0.859     & 0.785     & 0.776         \\
R2 Within 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
R2 Pseudo 
    &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
AIC & {{{-2623.7}}} & {{{-1828.7}}} & {{{-2054.8}}} & {{{-2417.0}}} & {{{-2337.2}}} & {{{-2306.4}}} 
    & {{{-2350.7}}} & {{{-2414.6}}} & {{{-2013.0}}} & {{{-2159.1}}} & {{{-2125.1}}} & {{{-1679.2}}} \\
BIC & {{{-2393.4}}} & {{{-1606.7}}} & {{{-1844.3}}} & {{{-2203.8}}} & {{{-2163.4}}} & {{{-2090.1}}} 
    & {{{-2120.4}}} & {{{-2207.1}}} & {{{-1794.2}}} & {{{-1962.9}}} & {{{-1917.6}}} & {{{-1460.3}}} \\
Log.Lik. 
    &{{{1364.856}}} & {{{966.334}}} &{{{1077.391}}} &{{{1258.501}}} &{{{1211.581}}} & {{{1204.196}}} 
    &{{{1228.360}}} &{{{1256.318}}} &{{{1057.525}}} &{{{1126.532}}} &{{{1111.542}}} & {{{890.587}}} \\
{Std. Errors\\ defined by:}
    & {{{Delstat}}} & {{{Delstat}}} & {{{Delstat}}} & {{{Delstat}}} & {{{Delstat}}} & {{{Delstat}}} 
    & {{{Delstat}}} & {{{Delstat}}} & {{{Delstat}}} & {{{Delstat}}} & {{{Delstat}}} & {{{Delstat}}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{sideways}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, column headers have shortened names, all `\num{...}` expression are replaced by `S` columns, for table is used `tabularray` package.

**Edit:** Added is missing part of table ..

Comment: @Mico, ups this is spurious code line remain from experimenting how to fit table on page. Had to be deleted ... Deleted now. And +1 for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Since you've provided no information about the document class, the paper size, the font and font size, and the margin widths employed by your LaTeX document, the following settings are mostly based on guesswork. Anyway, my main suggestion is to use the command `\rotatebox` (provided by the `graphicx` package) to render just the `tabular` material in landscape mode.

Do also try, as much as possible, to make some of the columns less wide, either by making the header cells less wide -- see below for a specific application of this idea -- or by moving repetitive but wide material, such as "by: Delstat", into a footnote. Taken together, these adjustments will let you get away with using `\small` (for a 10% linear reduction in font size) instead of `\scriptsize` (for a 30% reduction in font size). I'm pretty sure your readers will appreciate this gesture of yours.

By the way, why is each and every number in the table encased in a `\num` macro?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{sectsty} % just for this example
\sectionfont{\mdseries\scshape}
\usepackage{graphicx, % for \rotatebox macro
            siunitx,  % for \num macro
            booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, etc macros

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{4} % just for this example
\section{Appendix}

%\begin{table}
%\centering
%%%\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{ % do not, under any circumstance, use \resizebox
%\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont


\begingroup  % localize scope of the next instruction
\centering
\rotatebox{90}{%
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default value: 6pt
\small % 10% linear reduction in font size
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{12}{c} @{}}
\toprule
  & emp & \multicolumn{11}{c@{}}{emp\_} \\
  \cmidrule(l){3-13}
  & & incq1 & incq2 & incq3 & incq4 
  & incmiddle & incbelowmed & incabovemed 
  & ss40 & ss60 & ss65 & ss70 \\
\midrule
Treat$\times$After & \num{-0.007} & \num{0.006} & \num{-0.003} & \num{-0.004} & \num{-0.018}+ & \num{0.002} & \num{-0.003} & \num{-0.006} & \num{0.017} & \num{-0.004} & \num{-0.008} & \num{-0.038}+\\
 & (\num{0.012}) & (\num{0.018}) & (\num{0.015}) & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.013}) & (\num{0.015}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.018}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.020})\\
\addlinespace
Konstant & \num{-0.083}*** & \num{-0.190}*** & \num{-0.031}*** & \num{-0.059}*** & \num{-0.008}+ & \num{-0.048}*** & \num{-0.137}*** & \num{-0.017}*** & \num{-0.126}*** & \num{-0.137}*** & \num{-0.108}*** & \num{-0.167}***\\
 & (\num{0.006}) & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.004}) & (\num{0.006}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.013})\\
\midrule
Num.Obs. & \num{570} & \num{528} & \num{498} & \num{525} & \num{420} & \num{513} & \num{570} & \num{510} & \num{540} & \num{480} & \num{510} & \num{540}\\
R\textsuperscript{2} & \num{0.863} & \num{0.813} & \num{0.882} & \num{0.903} & \num{0.941} & \num{0.904} & \num{0.808} & \num{0.904} & \num{0.726} & \num{0.873} & \num{0.805} & \num{0.797}\\
R\textsuperscript{2} Adj. & \num{0.849} & \num{0.793} & \num{0.869} & \num{0.893} & \num{0.934} & \num{0.894} & \num{0.789} & \num{0.894} & \num{0.698} & \num{0.859} & \num{0.785} & \num{0.776}\\
R\textsuperscript{2} Within &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
R\textsuperscript{2} Pseudo &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
AIC & \num{-2623.7} & \num{-1828.7} & \num{-2054.8} & \num{-2417.0} & \num{-2337.2} & \num{-2306.4} & \num{-2350.7} & \num{-2414.6} & \num{-2013.0} & \num{-2159.1} & \num{-2125.1} & \num{-1679.2}\\
BIC & \num{-2393.4} & \num{-1606.7} & \num{-1844.3} & \num{-2203.8} & \num{-2163.4} & \num{-2090.1} & \num{-2120.4} & \num{-2207.1} & \num{-1794.2} & \num{-1962.9} & \num{-1917.6} & \num{-1460.3}\\
Log-Lik. & \num{1364.856} & \num{966.334} & \num{1077.391} & \num{1258.501} & \num{1211.581} & \num{1204.196} & \num{1228.360} & \num{1256.318} & \num{1057.525} & \num{1126.532} & \num{1111.542} & \num{890.587}\\
%%%Std.Errors & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat 
%%%           & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat & by: Delstat \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{13}{@{}l}{\footnotesize\textsuperscript{1} TODO: Fotnot till denna tabell}\\[0.5ex]
\multicolumn{13}{@{}l}{\footnotesize$^{+}\ p < 0.1$, $^{*}\ p < 0.05$, $^{**}\ p < 0.01$, $^{***}\ p < 0.001$.}\\[0.5ex]
\multicolumn{13}{@{}l}{\footnotesize All standard errors by Delstat.} % <-- new
\end{tabular}
%%%}  % do not, under any circumstance, use \resizebox
%%%\end{table}
} %end of scope of \rotatebox directive

\endgroup
\end{document}
```